# Allow access to a folder with HTACCESS

Tags: .htaccess, directory

I've been searching and I haven't found a solution that fits my need right now.

I have a website www.mywebsite.com and all its files are inside the public_html folder.

I want to create a folder called "uploads" inside public_html and then BE ABLE TO ACCESS it with www.mywebsite.com/uploads

I want it to list all the fles I've put there via FTP, but right now it shows me FORBIDDEN.

How can I be allowed to see the list of files and folders?
Thank you.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Subfolder directory browsing in Apache2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6686381/subfolder-directory-browsing-in-apache2)