# .htaccess modification for subdirectory access

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I followed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6686381/subfolder-directory-browsing-in-apache2) as a solution and my .htaccess now reads:

```
<DirectoryMatch  /mypath/to/my_subdir/(.)*/>
        Options +Indexes
</DirectoryMatch>
```

Yet when I visit my subdir (`http://www.example.org/my_sub/`) I am getting the following error message:

```
Internal Server Error

The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.

Please contact the server administrator at webmaster@mydomain.org to inform them of the time this error occurred, and the actions you performed just before this error.

More information about this error may be available in the server error log.

Additionally, a 500 Internal Server Error error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.
```

The .htaccess file noted above is living in `/public_html/` directory.

Comment: DirectoryMatch in htaccess??

Comment: @Starkeen yes thats right

Comment: This directive is not allowed in htaccess context . Read the documentation 

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html